# OnVsRestClassifier gives 0 accuracy

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, multilabel-classification

i am trying to solve a multilabel classification problem as

```
        from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer 

        traindf = pickle.load("traindata.pkl","rb"))
        X = traindf['Col1']
        X=MultiLabelBinarizer().fit_transform(X)

        y = traindf['Col2']
        y= MultiLabelBinarizer().fit_transform(y)

        Xtrain, Xvalidate, ytrain, yvalidate = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=.5)
        from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

        clf = OneVsRestClassifier(LogisticRegression(penalty='l2', C=0.01)).fit(Xtrain,ytrain)

        print "One vs rest accuracy: %.3f"  % clf.score(Xvalidate,yvalidate)
```

in this way, i always get 0 accuracy. Please point out if i am doing something wrong. i am new to multilabel classification. Here is what my data looks like

```
Col1                  Col2
asd dfgfg             [1,2,3]
poioi oiopiop         [4]
```

**EDIT**

Thanks for your help @lejlot. I think i am getting the hang of it. Here is what i tried

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier 
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

tdf = pd.read_csv("mul.csv", index_col="DocID",error_bad_lines=False)

print tdf
```

so my input data looks like

```
DocID   Content           Tags    
1       abc abc abc       [1]
2       asd asd asd       [2]
3       abc abc asd     [1,2]
4       asd asd abc     [1,2]
5       asd abc qwe   [1,2,3]
6       qwe qwe qwe       [3]
7       qwe qwe abc     [1,3]
8       qwe qwe asd     [2,3]
```

so this is just some test data i created. then i do

```
text_clf = Pipeline([
                     ('vect', TfidfVectorizer()),
                     ('clf', SGDClassifier(loss='hinge', penalty='l2',
                                            alpha=1e-3, n_iter=5, random_state=42)),
 ])

t=TfidfVectorizer()
X=t.fit_transform(tdf["Content"]).toarray()
print X
```

this gives me

```
[[ 1.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.          1.          0.        ]
 [ 0.89442719  0.4472136   0.        ]
 [ 0.4472136   0.89442719  0.        ]
 [ 0.55247146  0.55247146  0.62413987]
 [ 0.          0.          1.        ]
 [ 0.40471905  0.          0.91444108]
 [ 0.          0.40471905  0.91444108]]
```

then

```
y=tdf['Tags']
y=MultiLabelBinarizer().fit_transform(y)

print y
```

gives me

```
[[0 1 0 0 1 1]
 [0 0 1 0 1 1]
 [1 1 1 0 1 1]
 [1 1 1 0 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [0 0 0 1 1 1]
 [1 1 0 1 1 1]
 [1 0 1 1 1 1]]
```

here i am wondering why there are 6 column? **shouldn't there be only 3?**
anyway, then i also created a test data file

```
sdf=pd.read_csv("multest.csv", index_col="DocID",error_bad_lines=False)
print sdf
```

so this looks like

```
DocID  Content        PredTags             
34     abc abc qwe    [1,3]
35     asd abc asd    [1,2]
36     abc abc abc      [1]
```

i have the `PredTags` column to check for accuracy. So finally i fit and predict as

```
clf = OneVsRestClassifier(LogisticRegression(penalty='l2', C=0.01)).fit(X,y)
predicted = clf.predict(t.fit_transform(sdf["Content"]).toarray())
print predicted
```

which gives me

```
[[1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 0 1 1]
 [1 1 1 0 1 1]]
```

Now, how do i know which tags are being predicted? How can i check the accuracy against my `PredTags` column?

**Update**

Thanks a lot @lejlot :) i also manged to get the accuracy as follows

```
sdf=pd.read_csv("multest.csv", index_col="DocID",error_bad_lines=False)
print sdf

predicted = clf.predict(t.fit_transform(sdf["Content"]).toarray())
print predicted


ty=sdf["PredTags"]
ty = [map(int, list(_y.replace(',','').replace('[','').replace(']',''))) for _y in ty]

yt=MultiLabelBinarizer().fit_transform(ty)
Xt=t.fit_transform(sdf["Content"]).toarray()

print Xt
print yt
print "One vs rest accuracy: %.3f"  % clf.score(Xt,yt)
```

i just had to binarize the test set prediction column as well :)

Comment: this is not how you should work with **text** in classification. read scikitlearn manual on working with text before proceeding to building any model.

Comment: do you mean http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html

Comment: thanks, i will check it out. however at first glance it does not seem to have a use case for multilabel classification.

Comment: the multilabel classification is not an issue, you incorrectly work with text. Multilabel classification (in a basic form) **is just a set of independent binary classifiers**, nothing more.

Comment: thanks man, i will try to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual problem is the way you work with text, you should [**extract some kind of features**](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html) and use it as text representation. For example you can use **bag of words** representation, or tfidf, or any more complex approach.

So what is happening now? You call multilabelbinarizer on **list of strings** thus, scikit-learn creates a set of all iterables in the list... leading to the **set of letters** representation. So for example

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer 
X = ['abc cde', 'cde', 'fff']
print MultiLabelBinarizer().fit_transform(X)
```

gives you

```
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]])

        |  |  |  |  |  |  |
        v  v  v  v  v  v  v

        a  b  _  c  d  e  f
```

Consequently classification is nearly impossible as this does not capture any meaning of your texts.

You could do for example a Count Vectorization (bag of words)

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
print CountVectorizer().fit_transform(X).toarray()
```

gives you

```
      [[1  1  0]
       [0  1  0]
       [0  0  1]]

        |  |  |
        v  |  v
       abc | fff
           v
          cde
```

#### Update

Finally, to make predictions with labels, and not their binarization you need to **store your binarizer** thus

```
labels = MultiLabelBinarizer()
y = labels.fit_transform(y)
```

and later on

```
clf = OneVsRestClassifier(LogisticRegression(penalty='l2', C=0.01)).fit(X,y)
predicted = clf.predict(t.fit_transform(sdf["Content"]).toarray())
print labels.inverse_transform(predicted)
```

#### Update 2

If you only have three classes then the vector should have 3 elements, yours have 6 so check what you are passing as "y", there is probably some mistake in your data

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
MultiLabelBinarizer().fit_transform([[1,2], [1], [3], [2]])
```

gives

```
array([[1, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0]])
```

as expected.

My best guess is that your "tags" are also **strings** thus you actually call

```
MultiLabelBinarizer().fit_transform(["[1,2]", "[1]", "[3]", "[2]"])
```

which leads to

```
array([[1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]])

        |  |  |  |  |  | 
        v  v  v  v  v  v  

        ,  1  2  3  [  ]
```

And these are your 6 classes. Three true ones, 2 "trivial" classes "[" and "]" which are present **always** and also nearly trivial class "," which appears for every object beleonging to more than one class.

You should **convert your tags to actual lists first**, for example by

```
y = [map(int, list(_y.replace(',','').replace('[','').replace(']',''))) for _y in y]
```

Comment: so if i use  CountVectorizer().fit_transform(X).toarray() as argument to my classifier.fit() will it work?

Comment: classification is not an algorithmic task, there is no such thing as "if I do X, will it work" - this is just one, of possibly thousands of steps required to do it right. This is just the most basic approach which **might** do something.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help man. please see the edit. i feel that i am close to a solution. please correct me if i am wrong. really appreciate it

Comment: perfect man :) thank you so much. you are a really good teacher!